Interpolating the population of Canada
I have this data frame in R about quarterly population.
library(readr)
url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1710000901&latestN=0&startDate=19800101&endDate=20240701&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%5D%5D&checkedLevels="
data <- data.frame(read_csv(url))
data = data[data$GEO == "Canada",]
data$date_column <- as.Date(paste(data$REF_DATE, "-01", sep=""), format="%Y-%m-%d")
finaldf = data |> 
   dplyr::select(date_column,VALUE) |>
   dplyr::arrange(date_column)

From here, I am trying to interpolate the missing values (i.e. monthly values) using Gaussian Process and the plot the average results - just like they did here (https://www.rpubs.com/cboettig/greta-gp):

I am trying to interpolate (using a Gaussian Process) the monthly population values from the quarterly population values (along with their relative uncertainty, i.e. the multiple purple wavy bands).
I tried to adapt the code to work for my problem:
    library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12345)

finaldf$date_numeric <- as.numeric(finaldf$date_column)

SE <- function(Xi, Xj, l) {
  exp(-0.5 * (Xi - Xj)^2 / l^2)
}

cov_function <- function(X, Y, l) {
  outer(X, Y, SE, l)
}

x_predict <- seq(min(finaldf$date_numeric), max(finaldf$date_numeric), length.out = 100)
l <- 100

COV_prior <- cov_function(x_predict, x_predict, l)
values_prior <- mvrnorm(200, rep(0, length(x_predict)), COV_prior)

dat_prior <- data.frame(x = x_predict, t(values_prior)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))

ggplot(dat_prior, aes(x = x, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = rep), color = rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(title = "Gaussian Process Prior Samples", x = "Date (numeric)", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()

obs <- data.frame(x = finaldf$date_numeric, y = finaldf$VALUE)

jitter <- 1e-6

cov_xx_inv <- solve(cov_function(obs$x, obs$x, l) + jitter * diag(length(obs$x)))
Ef <- cov_function(x_predict, obs$x, l) %*% cov_xx_inv %*% obs$y
Cf <- cov_function(x_predict, x_predict, l) - cov_function(x_predict, obs$x, l) %*% cov_xx_inv %*% cov_function(obs$x, x_predict, l)

Cf <- Cf + jitter * diag(nrow(Cf))

values_post <- mvrnorm(200, Ef, Cf)

dat_post <- data.frame(x = x_predict, t(values_post)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))

gp <- data.frame(x = x_predict, Ef = Ef, sigma = 2 * sqrt(pmax(0, diag(Cf))))  # Use pmax to prevent negative values

ggplot(dat_post, aes(x = x, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = rep), color = rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.2) + # Posterior samples
  geom_ribbon(data = gp, aes(x, y = Ef, ymin = Ef - sigma, ymax = Ef + sigma), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4) + # Uncertainty band
  geom_line(data = gp, aes(x = x, y = Ef), size = 1) + # Posterior mean
  geom_point(data = obs, aes(x = x, y = y)) + # Observed data points
  labs(title = "Gaussian Process Posterior Samples", x = "Date (numeric)", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()

But I am unable to get a similar looking image:

Any recommendations on how I can fix this?

library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")

tryCatch({
    url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1710000901&latestN=0&startDate=19800101&endDate=20240701&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%5D%5D&checkedLevels="
    download.file(url, temp_file, mode = "wb")
    
    data <- data.frame(read_csv(temp_file))
    
    data <- data[data$GEO == "Canada",]
    data$date_column <- as.Date(paste(data$REF_DATE, "-01", sep=""), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    final_df <- data[,c("date_column", "VALUE")]
    
    final_df$date_column <- as.Date(final_df$date_column)
    
    current_date <- floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month")
    date_seq <- seq(from = min(final_df$date_column),
                    to = current_date,
                    by = "month")
    
    monthly_df <- data.frame(date_column = date_seq)
    
    merged_df <- merge(monthly_df, final_df, by = "date_column", all.x = TRUE)
    merged_df$VALUE_interpolated <- na.approx(merged_df$VALUE, na.rm = FALSE)
    
    
    
}, error = function(e) {
}, warning = function(w) {
}, finally = {
    if(file.exists(temp_file)) {
        unlink(temp_file)
    }
})


It looks like the concepts in your reference rely on the data being both Gaussian, (of which it definitely is not) and scaled. When I scaled your data, I changed l back to 1 and jitter to 1 -- I think you'll find what you're looking for. However, when you have 20,000 observations, you're missing more information than you're witnessing. (It's too much data to be meaningful.) (To scale data use the function scale().) Again, I wouldn't rely on these methods for meaningful statistics without adhering to the assumptions necessary for SS methods (normality, homogeneity...)

thank you for your advice kat ... I would be interested in seeing the visual produced from your side ... the purple colors look so beautiful!

Please clarify: Is the population data just toy data or is this a real-world application of the method? Population data is count data and you shouldn't use a multivariate normal to predict such data.

@ Roland: This was just a proof of concept, I am open to multiple ideas for this.

It's probably reasonable to use a Gaussian model to predict the population of Canada even though the values are technically discrete ...
