Add shading between points on ggplot
I have the following R code which downloads the population of Canada:
library(readr)
url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1710000901&latestN=0&startDate=19800101&endDate=20240701&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%5D%5D&checkedLevels="

data <- data.frame(read_csv(url))

data = data[data$GEO == "Canada",]
data$date_column <- as.Date(paste(data$REF_DATE, "-01", sep=""), format="%Y-%m-%d")
final_df = data[,c(10,15)]

From here, I made the following plot that interpolates missing data via simulation:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

generate_monthly_data <- function(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value, sd_factor = 0.01) {
    months_seq <- seq(start_date %m+% months(1), end_date %m-% months(1), by = "month")
    n_months <- length(months_seq)
    
    if (n_months > 0) {
        values <- seq(start_value, end_value, length.out = n_months + 2)[-c(1, n_months + 2)]
        sd <- sd_factor * mean(c(start_value, end_value))
        values <- values + rnorm(n_months, mean = 0, sd = sd)
        data.frame(date_column = months_seq, VALUE = round(values))
    } else {
        data.frame(date_column = as.Date(character()), VALUE = numeric())
    }
}

simulate_monthly_data <- function(df) {
    result <- data.frame()
    
    for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
        start_date <- df$date_column[i]
        end_date <- df$date_column[i+1]
        start_value <- df$VALUE[i]
        end_value <- df$VALUE[i+1]
        
        # Add the start point
        result <- rbind(result, df[i, ])
        
        # Generate and add intermediate months
        monthly_data <- generate_monthly_data(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value)
        result <- rbind(result, monthly_data)
    }
    
    # Add the last data point
    result <- rbind(result, df[nrow(df), ])
    
    result
}

set.seed(123)
simulations <- list()
for (i in 1:50) {
    simulations[[i]] <- simulate_monthly_data(final_df)
    simulations[[i]]$simulation <- i
}

all_simulations <- do.call(rbind, simulations)

mean_simulations <- all_simulations %>%
    group_by(date_column) %>%
    summarise(mean_VALUE = mean(VALUE))

legend_data <- data.frame(
    x = as.Date(c("1980-01-01", "1980-01-01")),
    y = c(max(all_simulations$VALUE), max(all_simulations$VALUE)),
    label = c("Simulation", "Original Data")
)

common_theme <- theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = all_simulations, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, group = simulation), 
              alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
    geom_point(data = final_df, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE), color = "red", size = 2) +
    geom_point(data = legend_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = label), size = 3) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Simulation" = "blue", "Original Data" = "red")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(suffix = " M", scale = 1e-6), 
                       breaks = seq(0, max(all_simulations$VALUE), by = 5000000)) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
    labs(title = "50 Simulations of Monthly Data",
         subtitle = "Red points show original quarterly data",
         x = "Date",
         y = "Value (Millions)",
         color = "Data Type") +
    common_theme

I am trying to modify this plot so that the blue simulation/uncertainty only appears between red points and not on the red points themselves. This reflects the fact that simulation uncertainty is only present in the regions between actual observed points and not on the actual observed points themselves.
Is there a way to do this in R?

The console output, not programming code, in your question, isn't great. In addition, when I remove the console output garbage, your code does not work. (For example an else within an if? That being said, ggplot creates a plot by layers, the same order in which you write them. As your red data is listed in the later layers it is on top of the blue. It's likely that no matter how you plot this when there is so much data, the red will disappear in the blue. I encourage you to edit your question by adding working code. I may be able to provide better help that way.

hello kat!  i have removed the console output

my apologies, try running the whole R code again ... now everything should run

Everything works, but I'm still not sure what you're looking for. I see that you made the points larger. If you wanted to simplest approach to making space, you could add duplicate layers of the red point data, but make the point size slightly larger and the color light gray or white... You could create line segments for every single day to avoid the line/point sharing space, but you wouldn't see it anyway with the whole order-of-layers (so a lot of work for no benefit). You could add multiple point layers with subsequent point size, colors (e.g., black, dark gray, gray, light gray, white).

Hello Kat - thank you for your reply. I am basically trying to make a diagram like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79054205/interpolating-the-population-of-canada

https://i.sstatic.net/8Rqr2hTK.png

I want to make it so that we see uncertainty between the points we are interpolating ... and 0 uncertainty at the actual point observed.

Hi Kat, can you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79054205/interpolating-the-population-of-canada?
